# Can VLANs coexist with a non-tagged LAN on the same interface?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, vlan

The questions is basically in the subject, but to give it a little more context:
Please consider a setup of 2 (embedded) systems, both running Linux. Each system has two physical NICs, named *eth0* and *eth1*. Only the one of these two systems has a physical connection to the (untagged) external network. To provide an external network connection to the second system, both systems are interconnected directly with their second NIC, and the first system bridges *eth0* to *eth1*, extending the external network to this interconnect. A graphical overview of this below:

```
External                Internal
network                 network
   |           +------------------------+           +----------
   |           |                        |           |
+--+---+   +---+--+                  +--+---+   +---+--+
| eth0 |   | eth1 |                  | eth0 |   | eth1 |
+----+-+   +-+--+-+                  +-+--+-+   +-+--+-+
     |       |  |                      |  |       |  |         
     +--+ +--+  |                      |  +--+ +--+  |         
        | |     |                      |     | |     |         
      +-+-+-+ +-+--------+    +--------+-+ +-+-+-+ +-+--------+
      | br0 | | eth1.100 |    | eth0.100 | | br0 | | eth1.100 |
      +--+--+ +----+-----+    +-----+----+ +--+--+ +----+-----+
         |         |                |         |         |
         |         |                |         |         |
         IP        P1               P1        IP        P2
```

On both systems, br0 is configured with a DHCP acquired IPv4 configuration to access the external network and this works beautifully, as expected.

However,both systems have a user-land process running, named P1, which needs to be able to communicate with its namesake on the other system. In order to achieve this, I have added a VLAN on either interconnecting NIC, to construct a second internal network, intended to be fully isolated from the external network bridged to the internal one.

**Now the question is**: Is the P1 <-> eth1.100 <-> eth0.100 <-> P1 connection completely isolated from the non-tagged external network traffic? Will there be no spillage between the P1 inter-system-communication and the either of the system's communication with the External network, and vice versa?